# React NotFoundError when list of elements re-rendered, integrated with `google.maps.OverlayView`

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

In my Next.js app I load up an array of paginated trips with a location before page render and display them on a google.maps.Map by using a `google.maps.OverlayView`.

Now the initial view rendering works seamlessly but then when I try to load a different set of trips, like the next page. I get the error

> `NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

Looking at other articles on Stackoverflow I found out that this happens when you:

1. Render something using React
2. Then, you manipulate DOM rendered by React with external script
3. Now on the next render cycle(re-render), React doesn't find the DOM node it rendered previously as its already modified/removed by external script

I got my OverlayView working by copying this code from [this google maps example code](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/blob/sample-overlay-popup/index.ts)
which I have committed [here](https://github.com/flov/hitchlog-nextjs/blob/a148cc501304ea8e8f17ea543059a992c27ca76f/pages/map.tsx#L83-L89)

Can anybody tell me why this happens when my `trips` state changes? The error disappears when I comment out the creation of the `Popups`. Thank you

Comment: I am having the same exact issue and still have not found the answer to this yet. Have you been able to resolve it? I would love it if someone could help with this one.

Comment: The link where you have commited does not seem to work.

Comment: @AlexRebula can you provide a minimal reproducible example for you case? That helps better address your problem.

Comment: @Yrll I've fixed the link.

Comment: @AlexRebula I've answered for OP's case. Not sure if it would help you. If you need me to look into your case, just post links.

Comment: @AlexRebula, were you able to fix the issue? I don't quite remember what I did to fix it. The issue was somewhere inside the Popup class.

Comment: @hackape, who is OP? :) Thank you for your answer though. I am testing it today and hopefully I will be able to use this to fix it.

Comment: @Flov, I do not know yet, only got to try today. Fingers crossed. Will let you know.

Comment: @AlexRebula  OP = original poster, Flov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the "why", OP has already got a pretty good idea:

> React doesn't find the DOM node it rendered previously as its already modified/removed by external script.

Now the question boils down to "what" exactly goes wrong in OP's code, which fits the above explanation?

---

OP mentioned when `new Popup()` is commented out, the error disappears, which gives us a clue that the error roots in the constructor of `Popup`. Let's look into [the constructor's code](https://github.com/flov/hitchlog-nextjs/blob/a148cc501304ea8e8f17ea543059a992c27ca76f/src/utils/Popup.ts#L17):

```js
class Popup extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  constructor(position: google.maps.LatLng, content: HTMLElement) {
    super();
    this.position = position;

    // This zero-height div is positioned at the bottom of the bubble.
    const bubbleAnchor = document.createElement('div');
    bubbleAnchor.classList.add('popup-bubble-anchor');
    bubbleAnchor.appendChild(content); //  ATTENTION TO THIS LINE!!!

    // This zero-height div is positioned at the bottom of the tip.
    this.containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    this.containerDiv.classList.add('popup-container');
    this.containerDiv.appendChild(bubbleAnchor);

    // Optionally stop clicks, etc., from bubbling up to the map.
    Popup.preventMapHitsAndGesturesFrom(this.containerDiv);
  }
```

We see some DOM manipulations happening here, but most importantly this line:

```
bubbleAnchor.appendChild(content)
```

Piece together with the code in [`map.tsx`](https://github.com/flov/hitchlog-nextjs/blob/a148cc501304ea8e8f17ea543059a992c27ca76f/pages/map.tsx#L88), where `new Popup()` is called, we can see the full picture.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //...
  const popup = new Popup(
    new google.maps.LatLng(
      trips[i]?.origin?.lat as number,
      trips[i]?.origin?.lng
    ),
    overlayRefs.current[i] as HTMLDivElement
  );
  //...
}, [])

// ...

{trips.map((trip, index) => (
  <div
    key={`tripOverlay${trip.id}`}
    ref={(element) =>
      overlayRefs.current.splice(index, 1, element as HTMLDivElement)
    }
  >...
```

In chronological order, these things happen:

1. `{trips.map((trip, index) => (<div ref={...}>...` trips rendered by React for 1st time.
2. DOMs are mounted, each trip div's ref is saved in `overlayRefs.current[i]`
3. `useEffect` kicks in, calls `new Popup(..., overlayRefs.current[i])`
4. Step into `Popup`'s constructor, `overlayRefs.current[i]` become the `content` arg, and it got appended to `bubbleAnchor`. This effectively removes it from it's original DOM tree location that React's aware of, and re-attaches it to a new parent that React doesn't know about.
5. Later `setTrips(data)` is called, `trips` changes and triggers a re-render, and step 1 happens for 2nd time.
6. React tries to update the DOM, remove old child node, but finds that it's no longer at the location that it's supposed to be, and boom, `NotFoundError` is thrown.

---

### Solution

We can still use React to render the `content` HTML, and then use "external script" to move it elsewhere.

The trick is to leave a dummy shell for React to check for, got it fooled into believing nothing goes wrong, but we secretly move the content within.

As long as the keyed element is at its original location, the content can be smuggled out and React wouldn't notice any difference. The moved content can still be update by React.

But once moved, you'll need to handle DOM removal yourself, otherwise you might have memory leak.

```
{trips.map((trip, i) => (
  // leave this keyed dummy shell untouched
  <div key={`tripOverlay${trip.id}`}>

    // the content is what's really useful to us
    // we can move it elsewhere with external script
    // and React wouldn't notice
    <div ref={(element) => overlayRefs.current.splice(i, 1, element)}>
    ...
```

I've created a code snippet example to demonstrate this trick. Also available on CodeSandbox.

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: "alpha", value: 0 },
    { id: "beta", value: 0 },
    { id: "gamma", value: 0 }
  ]);

  const bubbleRef = useRef();
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const refs = useRef([]).current;

  function addItem() {
    const id = inputRef.current.value;
    setData((data) => {
      return data.concat({ id, value: 0 });
    });
  }

  function moveElm(i) {
    bubbleRef.current.appendChild(refs[i]);
  }

  function deleteElm(id) {
    setData((data) => {
      return data.filter((d) => d.id !== id);
    });
  }

  function reset() {
    setData([
      { id: "alpha", value: 0 },
      { id: "beta", value: 0 },
      { id: "gamma", value: 0 }
    ]);
  }

  function random() {
    setData([
      { id: Math.random() + "", value: 0 },
      { id: Math.random() + "", value: 0 },
      { id: Math.random() + "", value: 0 }
    ]);
  }

  function bumpValue(i) {
    setData((data) => {
      data = data.slice();
      const t = data[i];
      data[i] = {
        ...t,
        value: t.value + 1
      };
      return data;
    });
  }

  function sortData() {
    setData((data) => {
      data = data.slice();
      data.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
      return data;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={bubbleRef}>
        <h3>Bubble</h3>
      </div>

      <h3>List</h3>
      <ol>
        {data.map((d, i) => (
          <li key={d.id}>
            <i>{d.id} dummy</i>
            {/* For comparison,
             * try move the ref={} part up to the <li> element.
             * "Move" any element and hit "Random Data" button,
             * you'll see the NotFoundError again
             */}
            <div ref={(e) => (refs[i] = e)}>
              {d.id.toUpperCase()} content: {d.value}
              <button onClick={() => bumpValue(i)}>+</button>
              <button onClick={() => moveElm(i)}>Move</button>
              <button onClick={() => deleteElm(d.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>

      <div>
        <h3>Buttons</h3>
        <button onClick={sortData}>Sort Data</button>
        <button onClick={random}>Random Data</button>
        <button onClick={reset}>Reset Data</button>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="id to add" ref={inputRef} />
          <button onClick={addItem}>Add Item</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<!-- require v16.8 and greater to support hooks -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[image: Edit modest-sound-hyepco]